# Dictionary - matching randomized keys with respective values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
facevalue={'A':1,'2':2,'3':3,'4':4,'5':5,'6':6,'7':7,'8':8,'9':9,'10':10,'J':10,'Q':10,'K':10}
deck = [key for key in self.facevalue.keys()]*4
card_values = [value for value in self.facevalue.values()]*4
```

This is a supposed deck of cards, namely one in blackjack.
Need help in defining a `hand_value` function.

```
import random
shuffled_deck = random.sample(deck, len(deck))
```

When I pop two cards, how can I get their corresponding values? The problem is that the keys and values are no longer together after shuffling. Say

```
def hand_value():
    hand = []
    for i in range(2):
        hand.append(shuffled_deck.pop())
    score = ???
    return score
```

What are the values that correspond to `hand[0]` and `hand[1]` ?

Let me rephrase that - after breaking up the dictionary, is there a way to match former keys with their corresponding values?

Comment: This would be much easier with a `Card` object that kept face and value together...

Comment: If you don't want to lookup again, you could consider storing it as tuples. Also, please take a look at `shuffle` for…shuffling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`deck` consists of the keys only; to get face values to match, simply look them up again:

```
[facevalue[card] for card in hand]
```

That produces a list of values for the picked hand; you can also use `sum()` and a generator expression to produce their total:

```
score = sum(facevalue[card] for card in hand)
```

Comment: I had thought that once I break up the dictionary I couldn't refer back to it, does work, though - thanks.

Comment: @AlvinLepik: all you did was *extract* information from the dictionary; you never altered the dictionary itself or lost the reference to it.